# Camunda migration from 7.17 to 7.20 schema error

Tags: camunda

While migration from Camunda 7.17 to 7.20
i got this error when deleting deployments with cascade.

```
Caused by: org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.PersistenceException: 
### Error querying database.  Cause: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column res.last_updated_ does not exist
  Position : 400
### The error may exist in org/camunda/bpm/engine/impl/mapping/entity/Task.xml
### The error may involve org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.persistence.entity.TaskEntity.selectTaskByQueryCriteria-Inline
### The error occurred while setting parameters
### SQL: select distinct           RES.REV_, RES.ID_, RES.NAME_, RES.PARENT_TASK_ID_, RES.DESCRIPTION_, RES.PRIORITY_,     RES.CREATE_TIME_, RES.OWNER_, RES.ASSIGNEE_, RES.DELEGATION_, RES.EXECUTION_ID_,     RES.PROC_INST_ID_, RES.PROC_DEF_ID_, RES.CASE_EXECUTION_ID_, RES.CASE_INST_ID_,     RES.CASE_DEF_ID_, RES.TASK_DEF_KEY_, RES.DUE_DATE_, RES.FOLLOW_UP_DATE_,     RES.SUSPENSION_STATE_, RES.TENANT_ID_, RES.LAST_UPDATED_                                           from ACT_RU_TASK RES                                                                                                                                                                                   WHERE  (         1 = 1 and            RES.PROC_INST_ID_ = ?         )          order by RES.ID_ asc     LIMIT ? OFFSET ?
### Cause: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column res.last_updated_ does not exist
  Position : 400
    at org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.wrapException(ExceptionFactory.java:30)
    at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.selectList(DefaultSqlSession.java:149)
    at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.selectList(DefaultSqlSession.java:140)
    at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.db.sql.DbSqlSession.lambda$executeSelectList$1(DbSqlSession.java:112)
    at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.util.ExceptionUtil.doWithExceptionWrapper(ExceptionUtil.java:350)
    ... 114 more
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column res.last_updated_ does not exist
  Position : 400
```

even if no schema migration is needed to migration form 7.17 to 7.20
here is the release notes
https://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.18/update/minor/717-to-718/#database-updates
https://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.19/update/minor/718-to-719/#database-updates
https://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.20/update/minor/719-to-720/#database-updates

and not patch in https://docs.camunda.org/manual/latest/installation/database-schema/#update

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For manual migration, I found my dabaBase scripts in :

https://artifacts.camunda.com/ui/native/camunda-bpm/org/camunda/bpm/distro/camunda-sql-scripts/7.18.0/

As described in:

https://docs.camunda.org/manual/latest/installation/database-schema/#update

Answer (score 0):

Actually that column is added by the migration script from 7.17 to 7.18.
See here for H2 database
https://github.com/camunda/camunda-bpm-platform/blob/master/engine/src/main/resources/org/camunda/bpm/engine/db/upgrade/h2_engine_7.17_to_7.18.sql